# <title> tag isn't showing up on the web page

Tags: html, tags, title, head

I was watching tutorials about html for beginners and tried to make a simple html file. 
when I open this on google chrome the body "hello" is showing up but the title part "first page" doesn't. Did I type something wrong? thanks in advance for your response.

//I apologies for those of you who already answered this. I now see that I have made a mistake on explaining my problem. I meant to show it as a header not title. I already got the answer from the given answers//

```
<html>
<head> 
   <title> first page </title>
</head>

<body> 
hello

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might be looking for the `h1` tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where do you expect title to be shown?

Title is what usually is displayed in the tab bar of your browser, or as text in your window switcher in your operating system. It does not show up inside your webpage.

Your markup seems to be correct, just look for the title in the browser window.

If you meant to make a title (in the meaning of a large text displaying in your website) one way of doing this is to, below your body-tag, write

```
<h1>Title here</h1>.
```

Comment: Thank you now I see it, I should've looked there first thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

`<title>` is not showing in web page; it is shown in **Tab / Window's title**.

Suggested to learn the basic HTML structure first.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want a header

```
<html>
<head> 
   <title>my page </title>
</head>

<body> 

<h1> first page </h1>
hello

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I learned that the title is the meta tag (the SEO bits), and the H1 is what shows up on the page. So if you'd like both to be the same, example: Things I've Learned is the title and the header of your website, you'd repeat the line.

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Things I've Learned</title>
</head>

<body> 

<h1>Things I've Learned</h1>

<p>These are the things</p>


</body>
</html>
```

VIA QUORA:
"The key difference between these tags is where their content appears. That difference impacts how search engines and web surfers analyze your page. Title Tag: The Title Tag is known as a meta tag. ... Because it displays the largest text, the H1 Header tag is often used to create a title at the top of the page."

More on how to optimize titles for search engines [here](https://www.v9digital.com/blog/2015/01/08/h1-headers-title-tags-seo/).