# Django master template doesn't display title block

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I'm a bit of a noob regarding django framework. I started learning it today and I already have an issue with what I've done and I couldn't figure out why.

I wanted to setup a master template, called `master.html` and use 2 other pages: `all_members.html` and `details.html`

Here is the exact code:

###### master.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

###### all_members.html

```
{% extends "master.html" %}

{% block title %}
        My Tennis Club - List of all members
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
  <h1>Members</h1>

  <ul>
    {% for x in mymembers %}
      <li><a href="details/{{ x.id }}">{{ x.firstname }} {{ x.lastname }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

###### details.html

```
{% extends "master.html" %}

{% block title %}
  Details about {{ mymember.firstname }} {{ mymember.lastname }}
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
  <h1>{{ mymember.firstname }} {{ mymember.lastname }}</h1>

  <p>Phone {{ mymember.phone }}</p>
  <p>Member since: {{ mymember.joined_date }}</p>

  <p>Back to <a href="/dev">Members</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is what the page looks like:

[image]

To be sure, the title "My Tennis Club" should be displayed, right ?

I can't figure out why it could not...

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<title> tag isn't showing up on the web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630645/title-tag-isnt-showing-up-on-the-web-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML <title> tag sets text displayed within the browser's title bar - NOT inside page content.
Here's a nice W3 tutorial page about this tag: [<title>](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_title.asp)

Probably it's getting set as expected - but on the title bar?

Comment: How my god, it does. I understand now. Feeling a bit stupid^^  Thank you for the answer

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone from time to time 